# How to view office interop word comparison in console

Tags: c#, console, compare, office-interop

I am looking to compare two word documents and I found a solution online that compares word documents using c#. When the code is executed, it opens three applications (the original document, the document that needs to be compared, and a third document that shows the results). Is there a way for these three application to not open up and instead return a boolean to the console?

`objective: Display the comparison of the two documents in a console application as either 'the same' or 'different'`

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
      Application wordApp = new Application();
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        object wordTrue = (object)true;
        object wordFalse = (object)false;
        object fileToOpen = @"C:\doc1.docx";
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        Document doc1 = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileToOpen,
               ref missing, ref wordFalse, ref wordFalse, ref missing,
               ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
               ref missing, ref missing, ref wordTrue, ref missing,
               ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        object fileToOpen1 = @"C:\doc2.docx";
        Document doc2 = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileToOpen1,
               ref missing, ref wordFalse, ref wordFalse, ref missing,
               ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
               ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
               ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        Document doc = wordApp.CompareDocuments(doc1, doc2, WdCompareDestination.wdCompareDestinationNew, WdGranularity.wdGranularityWordLevel,
            true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, "", true);

     //Something like the following:
     if (doc1 != doc2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("They are not same");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("They are identical");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using interops like `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, so you can hide the windows using :

```
wordApp.Visible = false;
```

and Finally :

```
wordApp.Quit();
```

A faster approach is however, reading them in byte. you can compare the two byte arrays to figure out how similar they are.

Comment: i get a "File In Use" error when i set the visibility to false

Comment: @DesmondLost: if you don't terminate the application, it will be still running but invisibly in your system, so file will be definitely in use !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set Visible = false? 
I think this is why your word documents pops up.
I did some word docs manipulation in the past, and by setting visible property to false, you can work with the doc without showing it. (winword.exe will execute anyway)

Comment: that helps but I get a pop up message box that states "dox1.docx is locked for editing."

Comment: Are you sure you don't have opened the doc using winword.exe (or other app) at the same time you try to modify it. It happens to me a lot. I'll close everything and start from scratch.

Comment: look at the finally block in the code of this post. This is the way you should close and finish your app. (To avoid memory leaks for once and weird behavior) http://alemiralles.blogspot.com.ar/search?q=word

Comment: I set it up like your example, but I still get the same issue